# Array to String conversion error on server using laravel eloquent Create

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-vue

First of all I must tell you that my code is working on my localhost, the error I am getting is only on development server after deployment.

I am getting error on `$list = Listing::create($data);`

Here is my payload for $data

```
array:25 [
  "seller1_name" => "Seller 1"
  "seller2_name" => "Seller 2 test"
  "listing_date" => "2020-12-17"
  "listing_expire_date" => "2020-12-29"
  "address" => "New addrs"
  "city" => "new city"
  "state" => "new state"
  "zip" => "1231231"
  "list_price" => "4343434"
  "step_template_id" => 8
  "broker_fee_type" => "$"
  "transaction_fee" => "342342342342"
  "cobroker_split_type" => "$"
  "school_district" => "dsadasad"
  "broker_fee" => "3424234"
  "cobroker_split" => "34243"
  "agents" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "key" => 78
      "value" => "Agent1 user"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "key" => 84
      "value" => "Agent2 user"
    ]
  ]
  "admin_id" => 68
  "login_user_id" => 68
  "login_email" => "webkeeda@yopmail.com"
  "chargebee_plan_id" => "starter"
  "customer_id" => "AzZlzTSI5w7bDEMt"
  "role_id" => 1
  "user_company" => null
  "created_by" => 68
]
```

My Listing.php Model have many to many relation

```
public function agents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'listing_agents', 'listing_id', 'agent_id');
    }
```

If you need any other information from my end please let me know in the comment.

**EDIT:**

To store data in my relation I am using this.

```
$agents = $request->agents;
            array_walk($agents, function (& $item, $key, $listing) {
                $item['listing_id'] = $listing->id;
                $item['agent_id'] = $item['key'];
                unset($item['key']);
            }, $listing);

            if($listing) {
                $listing->listing_agents()->createMany($agents);
            }
```

Relation:

```
public function listing_agents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ListingAgent', 'listing_id');
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: well `agents` is an array ... it isn't going to automatically break that off and deal with it as a relationship

Comment: `Array to string conversion` on Str, I tried to use $e->getTrace() but it was long list of files where data travelled. Couldn't exactly get where the error came from.

Comment: I have updated my code, how I am storing data in my relation.

Comment: remove/unset the `agents` key completely before you pass that to `create`

Comment: lagbox Can you add the answer with little more information on that?

Comment: are you using `$fillable` or `$guarded` on the model?

Comment: I am using $guarded

Comment: that explains part of the problem, its better to use `$fillable` because anything that isn't in "fillable" won't make it to the database ... when you use 'guarded', everything that isn't in 'guarded' will get sent to the database

Comment: If the issue is related to my code shouldn't it show on both local and server. Why only on server and not on my local system?

Comment: well you are sending an array as a field value for the record, it is eventually going to try and convert that to a string unless there is some casting or a mutator involved

Comment: So, can this issue also resolve by adding "agents" in $guarded right?